# See the waterboys

Tags: steganography

> Firsts, grown-up breaks, coiling equinoxes hatching.
>   Holidays burning, common camping, beaches bright.
>   A butternut's harvest-time, bumblebees come falling.
>   Following chill, frozen ice-carpets evoke Christmas.

Comment: Hmmm.... every letter except 'J'...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The riddle ...

> ... describes and hides the **four seasons**.
>
> All words start with letters from A to I. The first word, "firsts" refers to the first blossoms in spring, but it is also ba a hint towards the significance of the first letters. Now take the first letter from words that start with an A, the second from words that start with a B, and so on, to get:
>
> First**s**, grown-u**p** b**r**eaks, co**i**ling equi**n**oxes hatchin**g**.   →   **spring**
>      Holiday**s** b**u**rning, co**m**mon ca**m**ping, b**e**aches b**r**ight.   →   **summer**
>      **A** b**u**tternut's harvest-**t**ime, b**u**mblebees co**m**e falli**n**g.   →   **autumn**
>      Follo**w**ing ch**i**ll, froze**n** ice-carpe**t**s evok**e** Ch**r**istmas.   →   **winter**
>
> Very nice. I don't know what to make of the title, though.

Comment: Gratifyingly beautiful exposition! (A two-bit title: water ~ sea - boys ~ sons.)